# How to use instead of for trigger in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
create or replace trigger beforeInsert
instead of insert on Friends
for each row



begin
dbms_output.put_line('This operation is prohibited');
end beforeInsert;
```

I am trying to create a trigger that would show a message 'This operation is prohibited' instead of inserting into table , but get a compilation error. Oracle IDE requires me to specify either before of after. What is wrong? I know that `instead of` is used for views, but how can I prohibit an insert to a table using a trigger?

Comment: Do you want to raise an exception?  It doesn't make sense to do something like call `dbms_output.put_line` in a trigger where you have no way of knowing whether the caller even allocated a buffer to write the output to or whether the caller will display your message.  It doesn't make sense to allow an `INSERT` statement to do appear to succeed to the calling application but not actually do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSTEAD OF` triggers can only be created on Views.

For a table, you can create `BEFORE` or `AFTER` triggers. In fact, you can create four different types of triggers on tables, depending on your requirements:

```
BEFORE STATEMENT
  BEFORE ROW
  AFTER ROW
AFTER STATEMENT
```

As for your requirement, if you want to prohibit inserting into a table, don't use a trigger. Revoke the INSERT privilege from the user instead.